# Plotting an array of vectors in Python (pyplot)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to plot a large array of vectors using pyplot. Right now I've got

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import operator

t = np.arange(0, np.pi, .01)


def pos1(t):
    x1 = .72 * np.cos(13*t)
    y1 = .72 * np.sin(13*t)
    return x1, y1


def pos2(t):
    x2 = np.cos(8*t)
    y2 = np.sin(8*t)
    return x2, y2


def vec(t):
    x1 = pos1(t)[0]
    x2 = pos2(t)[0]
    y1 = pos1(t)[1]
    y2 = pos2(t)[1]
    x = np.subtract(x1, x2)
    y = np.subtract(y1, y2)
    return x, y


X = pos2(t)[0]
Y = pos2(t)[1]
U = vec(t)[0]
V = vec(t)[1]

plot1 = plt.figure()
plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, headlength=4)
plt.show(plot1)
```

Where `pos1(t)`, `pos2(t)` and `vec(t)` are functions that return a tuple of the form `([a,...,z],[a1,...,z1])`.

This plot gives me something close to what I want, but the vector lengths are all wrong. the two functions, `pos1(t),pos2(t)` return a tuple of the point on a particular curve, and the `vec(t)` function is their difference, leading to a vector from a point on the first curve to a point on the second. My plot has the correct direction, but not magnitude.

[image]

Comment: It's impossible for us to help you unless you tell us what `pos2` and `vec` are. Also, please tell us what your expected output is. Lastly, is there a typo in your snippet? Is it supposed to be `X = pos1(t)`? `pos1` is currently not referenced anywhere in your snippet.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the entire thing. The output I'd like to get is a plot of all the distance vectors, vec(t), from pos1 to pos2, at the position it was at at t.

Comment: The picture is what you want to get, not what your code does for you, right? Because you sample produces different output.

Comment: @DJV I really want to do an unanimated version of this: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/2AXLIVGTzzX2OU9C9ZBukdyGVriKf9ezp1ct3mIzKpZG6k8G6gS5V4aJt_hk6OXmk2TmxU4gC9Hks93e0NcsJ84agzYPDf2pVhkmeGcULK3HqaSqebT5EduTx_gduDYAVzCngb0

Comment: I think the relative speeds of the two points in that gif you've linked is important. I'm guessing those are planets? Earth and Venus? Do you know how many revolutions one planet undergoes relative to the other in that figure?

Comment: @Astrum That picture definetely clarifies what you are trying to do. Check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quiver` handles length of arrows. It seems `quiver` is not what you need.

**Using regular `plot`:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.01)
x0 = np.sin(8 * t)
y0 = np.cos(8 * t)
x1 = 0.72 * np.sin(13 * t)
y1 = 0.72 * np.cos(13 * t)

data = np.column_stack((x0, x1, y0, y1)).reshape(-1, 2)

plt.plot(*data, color='black')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]
**Original:**

[image: Original]

Comment: How exactly does the line "data = np.stack((x0, x1, y0, y1)).T.reshape(-1, 2)" work? You're combining the arrays with the first arguement, but what about the T.reshape(-1,2)?

Comment: `reshape(-1, 2)` "groups" by 2 elements in a "row" (-1 allows not to calculate number of "rows", it says "calculate this dimension for me, based on others"). If we wont make `T` operation, reshape will iterate through whole `x0` array, then through whole `x1`, ... , resulting array would be wrong: `[[x0[0], x0[1]], [x0[2], x0[3]], ...]`. With `T` operation we iterate correctly and get resulting array as: `[[x0[0], x1[0]], [y0[0], y1[0]], [x0[1], x1[1]], [y0[1], y1[1]]]`. This is correct data we want to feed to `plot`.

Comment: Changed it to use `column_stack`. It is probably clearer.

Comment: Ok, so the only thing I still am not clear on is why this is plotting the vectors. I guess I don't really understand how the plot function is working. What exactly is the * doing in front of data?